# Magento2 : Reviews error message

Tags: magento-2.1, product-review

while submit the review its getting "**We can't post your review right now**"  instead of "**You submitted your review for moderation**".Why it is showing .

Is it backend setting?

Comment: Each review should be approved by admin. Then only, it would get displayed under the product. No backend settings to auto approve the reviews. you have to modify the code for that to work

Comment: You should check error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check this file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Review\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Review\Controller\Product as ProductController;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Review\Model\Review;

class Post extends ProductController
{
    /**
     * Submit new review action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        $data = $this->reviewSession->getFormData(true);
        if ($data) {
            $rating = [];
            if (isset($data['ratings']) && is_array($data['ratings'])) {
                $rating = $data['ratings'];
            }
        } else {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            $rating = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', []);
        }
        if (($product = $this->initProduct()) && !empty($data)) {
            /** @var \Magento\Review\Model\Review $review */
            $review = $this->reviewFactory->create()->setData($data);
            $review->unsetData('review_id');

            $validate = $review->validate();
            if ($validate === true) {
                try {
                    $review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
                        ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
                        ->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
                        ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                        ->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                        ->setStores([$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                        ->save();

                    foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
                        $this->ratingFactory->create()
                            ->setRatingId($ratingId)
                            ->setReviewId($review->getId())
                            ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                            ->addOptionVote($optionId, $product->getId());
                    }

                    $review->aggregate();
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You submitted your review for moderation.'));
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t post your review right now.'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                if (is_array($validate)) {
                    foreach ($validate as $errorMessage) {
                        $this->messageManager->addError($errorMessage);
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t post your review right now.'));
                }
            }
        }
        $redirectUrl = $this->reviewSession->getRedirectUrl(true);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($redirectUrl ?: $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

in 2 cases it can fail ( as per error message shared ) as you can see from code. Just debug, do some print_r to check and fix