# Magento 2.3 Reviews error message - We can't post your review right now

Tags: magento2.3, magento-community, review, product-review

If I click "Submit Review" button,
I am getting error :

"We can't post your review right now."

Have a any idea? Thank you.[image]

Comment: You can refer the link. if you have help for sane.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156201/magento2-reviews-error-message

Answer (score 1):

Need more detail regarding this. This message is custom not actual. So for debugging purpose can you write a core file and update original error message here?

1. **vendor/magento/module-review/Controller/Product/Post.php**

Line 69: add **$e->getMessage()** which is original exception. Now should looks like:

```
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
    $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t post your review right now.'.$e->getMessage()));
}
```

2. Other case is if form validation is wrong. That means Title, Nickname, and Detail should be required field. So added something error message here to.

```
$this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
if (is_array($validate)) {
    foreach ($validate as $errorMessage) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($errorMessage);
    }
} else {
    $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t post your review right now. --- TEST'));
}
```

**Note:** *After you got an actual exception, then please undo your core change with the original code. Core file modification is not good.*

Comment: Thank you, I added .$e->getMessage())); this code. but still same error.

Comment: Did you check to validate method? vendor/magento/module-review/Model/Review.php::validate?

Comment: Sorry, I tried again. And I add .$e->getMessage())); this code. And I cleaned cache. Now I saw this message.  We can't post your review right now.SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s), query was: SELECT `rating_option`.* FROM `rating_option` WHERE (`rating_option`.`option_id`='38', '34', '45')

Comment: Admin > Store > Attributes > Rating = If I do quality and value disable, comment system working. What can I do now? thanks.

Comment: Did you make any customize here? Default with sample data working fine.

Comment: I changed only rating name. Now, I did default name. Still same. I am thinking, I installed aitoc review extension a week ago, and then I removed it. Maybe becaouse of this? I dont know.

Comment: Not sure about the third part extension. But if you change query SELECT rating_option.* FROM rating_option WHERE (rating_option.option_id IN ('38', '34', '45')) then should work

Comment: How can I do this? And (rating_option.option_id IN ('38', '34', '45')) , 38 means 5 stars. For example if I give 4 stars for first rating , this id is changing.

Comment: Sorry man, it's really difficult to help you with third party paid module modification error.

Comment: Hey @EK. Were you able to find solution. I am having same problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems this SQL error

Missed data form some REVIEW* tables.

**Maybe after cleanup test data** :)

Solution -
setup fresh & clean Magento 2.

Copy SQL export of data for tables review_status & review_entity,

import to DB of Magento with review bug.

But be carefull with SQL query.